# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException when deleting row from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on an app that will update and add user's coordinate to a UITableView when the user has traveled over a preset distance interval. The coordinates will be automatically added to an NSMutableArray, and I use the array to update the table.

Everything load up and work fine (I can edit the table by moving and re-ordering the rows) but whenever I chose to delete a specific row, the program crash with the error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".

```
- (void) tableView:( UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:( UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:( NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSArray *items = [[G5SharedStore sharedStore]allCoords];
        G5SharedStore *item = items[indexPath.row];
        [[G5SharedStore sharedStore]removeItem:item];
        //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

The last line is what causes the error, but I'm new to objective-c, so I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:
Ok, I played around with the code this morning and it works. The problem is that the array keeps adding more and more items, but the tableview doesn't, unless I go back out and click "show table" button again to refresh it. So whenever I delete something in the tableview, the table's size is inconsistent with the array's size therefore I get the error. Here's my new problem, I tried to solve the above problem by making the table automatically update its data using:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

The table does update, but it keeps adding blank cells ... with no data in it. Here's where I added the above:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@" UITableViewCell"
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSArray *items = [[G5SharedStore sharedStore] allCoords];
        G5SharedStore *item = items[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [item description];
        [tableView reloadData];
        return cell;
}
```

Since I just started iOS programming 1 month ago, I could be wrong. So please guide me.

Thanks again everyone

Comment: No I'm not, I tried that while googling around for fixes but came up with the same error.

Comment: Hi, could you please post the entire error message in the question?

Comment: 2014-07-02 04:00:29.902 Tracker[23645:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 163861312 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'

Looks like I'm asking the program to delete a row that doesn't exist in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems:

Firstly [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) recommends modifying the table view **before** the data-model (you are doing it the other way round):

> It must do two things:
>
> Send `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to the table view to direct
>   it to adjust its presentation.
>
> Update the corresponding data-model array by either deleting the referenced item from the array or adding an item to the array.

Secondly you don't appear to be calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` around that call. To quote the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a):

> Note the behavior of this method when it is called in an animation
>   block defined by the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods.

Comment: But I thought I removed the item from the array with this code [[[G5ShareStore sharedStore]removeItem:item]; already? However I just found out another error. While the tableView only display the contents up to the point when I click "show table" button, the array itself keeps updating and adding more coordinate. When I do an NSLog to check on the function, deleting the first row on the screen gives me a console output of deleting the very last item in the array ...

Comment: @kevinnguyen it's about the *order* you do it in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of delete row delete object from the array and reload table

```
- (void) tableView:( UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:( UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:( NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSArray *items = [[G5SharedStore sharedStore]allCoords];
    G5SharedStore *item = items[indexPath.row];
    [[G5SharedStore sharedStore]removeItem:item];

    //Remove this
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    //Add This Line
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

}

Comment: How does `reloadData` help?

Comment: when you delete object from the array then reload data then it will reload table with following manner 1. set number or row (count of coordinate array which is reduced by one) 2. create cells from the coordinate array data will result in deleted one row.

Comment: So you are saying that `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` should not be used?

Comment: normally i does not use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method

Comment: how ? can you explain me ? it will help me to correct my mistakes.

Comment: Because the `insertRows...` and `deleteRows` methods, give excellent user feedback as to what has changed in a table, especially when they are animated.  Doing a `reloadData` means the user must examine the table closely to determine what has changed, and is therefore rubbish.